# Replacing a array of objects vuejs

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I need to replace a reactive array of object with vuejs, 
I retrieve data form Api Restful, and then I listen if there is a change on the object.

For example I got a list of users with status (online, offline, busy), if a user changes their status I need to update the object already rendered.

The solution that I found is to find and delete the object then pushed the new data, but in this case I lose the order of elements in the DOM since the new data is appended in the last:

```
<template>
    <section>
       <div v-for="expert in experts"  :key="expert.id">
            <div class="spinner" :class="expert.status"></div>
       </div>
    </section>
</template>
    <script>
        import axios from 'axios'

        export default {
            name: 'experts',
            data: () => ({
                experts: [],
                errors: []
            }),
        // Fetches posts when the component is created.
        created() {
            axios.get(`http://siteapi.co/api/v1/users`)
            .then(response => {
          // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
          this.experts = response.data.data
          })
            .catch(e => {
                this.errors.push(e)
            })
        },
        mounted() {
            this.listen(); 
        },

        methods: {
          listen: function() {
             var self = this
             //Listen if there is a status change
             this.pusher.subscribe('expert-front', channel => {
                channel.bind('edit', (data) => {
                  //Fid the object and deleted 
                  self.experts = self.experts.filter(function (item) {
                      return item.id != data.id;
                  });
                   self.experts.push(data)
                });
            });
          }
        }
    }  
    </script>
```

Comment: you could store the index of the expert in the experts array using a for loop, before removing it. Then just insert the new expert object into the same index in the array using `self.experts.splice(index, 0, data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of filtering and pushing the data, you can do something like this:

```
      listen: function() {
         var self = this
         this.pusher.subscribe('expert-front', channel => {
            channel.bind('edit', (data) => {
              //Find the index of the item chag
              let index = self.experts.findIndex((expert) => expert.id === data.id)

              self.experts = [
                ...self.experts.slice(0, index - 1),
                data,
                ...self.experts.slice(index + 1)
              ]
            });
        });
      }
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: thanks you @aks  , 
I did not understand very well this part of code :  self.experts = [
                ...self.experts.slice(0, index - 1),
                data,
                ...self.experts.slice(index + 1)
              ]

Comment: These are new features in ES2015.
So what I do is first get all items from 0 to index -1,
then I get all item from index + 1 to the end.

The thing is slice will return an array so the end result can become an array of arrays like [[], []].

So the `...` just help flatten the value